# Vue обновление данных на странице

Tags: vue.js

Имеется небольшой проект на Vue Cli + Flask.
Ситуация такая. с Vue я через axios отправляю запрос на бэк в бд и мне возвращается ответ как у всех как и везде. В ответе приходит json, есть ключ значение которого говорит, что есть ли запись такая в бд или нет. Так вот, все проходит отлично, первый раз когда нажимаешь на кнопку, отрабатывает метод и это значение выводится на страницу, мол "такая запись в бд есть". Я изменяю данные, чтобы уж точно не было похожих записей, отправляю повторно запрос на бэк, данные приходят, что такой записи нет, в консоли выводится, все  отлично, но вот на странице ничего не меняется, надпись "такая запись в бд есть" не меняется, на "такой записи в бд нет". Как все-таки делать, чтобы после promis данные обновлялись на странице, не понимаю я как запустить обновление виртуального DOM.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      formDataAddPrinter: {
        name: '',
        note: '',
        vendorCode: ''
      },
      updateDate: false,
      msg: '',
      resMsg: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendDataAddPrinter: function() {
      const self = this
      this.axios.post('http://192.168.0.197:5000/api/add/printer', {
          formData: this.formDataAddPrinter
        })
        .then(function(res) {
          console.log(res.data.msg)
          self.resMsg = res.data.msg
          self.updateDate = true
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          self.updateDate = true
          console.log(self.updateDate)
          console.log(self.resMsg)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container-printer">
  <div class="container-form-add-printer">
    <div class="static" v-bind:class="{'msg-add-printer': updateDate}">{{ resMsg }}</div>
    <div class="form-add-printer">
      <div class="label-param name-printer">
        <label for="name-printer">Название принтера</label>
        <input type="text" id="name-printer" v-model="formDataAddPrinter.name">
      </div>
      <div class="label-param note-printer">
        <label for="note-printer">Примечание к принтеру</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="note-printer" v-model="formDataAddPrinter.note"> </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="label-param vendor-code-printer">
        <label for="vendor-code-printer">Артикул</label>
        <input type="text" id="vendor-code-printer" v-model="formDataAddPrinter.vendorCode">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn add-btn" value="Добавить" v-on:click="sendDataAddPrinter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: с примером кода будет понятнее в чем проблема

Comment: Добавил по просьбе. Этот компонент выводится в модальном окне.

Comment: для вставки полноценного примера кода(html, css, js) можно использовать *Фрагмент кода*(комбинация Ctrl+M)

Comment: посмотрите этот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/fn1qkzut/) все работает, на странице все обновляется

Comment: Так у меня тоже самое, возможно быть из-за того, что компонент подключен и отображается в модальном окне. У меня компонент в компоненте, как раз это дочерний компонент.

Comment: не совсем тоже самое, я убрал self и использовал this и в обработчики промиса объявлены стрелочными функциями, я думаю все дело в этом

Answer (score 2):

Вместо:

```
self.resMsg = res.data.msg
```

Должно быть:

```
this.resMsg = res.data.msg
```

Вы перепутали this с self

Comment: нет я не перепутал выше поглядите там написано const self = this. Если использовать this то он будет брать объект axios и скажет, что такой переменной не существует.

Comment: @ТохаКартоха скорее всего это связано с реактивностью vue и недоработками в js. Vue не может отследить такое изменение. Попробуйте всё-таки использовать this и вносить изменения в this, a не в self. Для этого замените функциональные выражения на стрелочные функции, чтобы контекст this не терялся

Comment: я бы с радостью в this вносил но он ссылается на объект axios а не Vue.$data ладно будем думать, что да как

Comment: @ТохаКартоха в js ES6 появились стрелочные функции, они не имеют своего this, в отличие от функциональных выражений. Более подробно о них можно узнать тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics

Comment: Да я знаю просто привык к обычным функциям и стрелочные стараюсь не использовать, спасибо но это не решает мою проблему. Надпись в шаблоне не меняется ((

Comment: @ТохаКартоха Как это не решает? Вы поменяли self на this?

Comment: Если оставлять стрелочные финкции то нет смысла было менять. Правильно если сделать обычные функции то this отрабатывал бы нормально. Спасибо я уже разобрался. Прошу прощения за долгий ответ.